# How to get only one role from a set of roles

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a simple spring security project where basically I have user and role entities. I have a set of roles "ADMIN" and "USER".

Now I want to assign only "USER" role along with creating a new user.

I have tried to use List and collections with the same problem.

The User entity has  `Set<Role>`

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int user_id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_name", unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "roles")
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;}
```

And Role entity:

```
public class Role {

    }
    @Id
    private int role_id;
    private String role;

}
```

And here is the saveMyUser method to save the user to my database.
When I use:

```
public void saveMyUser(User user) {
    Set<Role> hash_Set = new HashSet<Role>();
    user.setPassword(encoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll())); <--- Here
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

`user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));` assign all roles to the user, since I want for new user only assign the "USER" role.

I tried `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findByRole(2)));` and also I tried `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findByID(2)));` with this error: Cannot infer type arguments for HashSet<>.

Role table in my database:

```
role_id    role
1          ADMIN
2          USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HashSet` constructor takes a `Collection`, not a single element. This line:

```
user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
```

creates a new HashSet with all of your roles. This line

```
user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findByRole(2)));
```

tries to create a new HashSet with a single element in the constructor, which won't work as a Role is not an instance of Collection.

Just fetch your role, create a HashSet, add the role and THEN set the user's role:

```
Role role = roleRepository.findByRole(2);
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
roles.add(role);
user.setRoles(roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Spring Data repository then one issue is that the query names/parameter types you've chosen don't match your entity. There's no field called "ID", and the type of `role` is `String`, not `int`.

Your best option would be to make your repository method signature

```
Role findByRole(String roleName);
```

You should also change the name and data type of the ID in your `Role` object - by convention Java uses camelCase, not snake_case, and while an int is probably fine for a table like ROLE that's likely to stay small, in a general case you'll want the larger keyspace that `long` gives you. It's also nicer to have a consistent datatype for your ids across your objects - it saves you from having to think "wait, was this one an int or a long?". It should be `private long roleId;`.

Answer (score 0):

Controller code:

```
@PostMapping("/do_register")
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) 
{       
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findByName("USER")));
    user.setEnabled(true);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "signup";
}
```

Role Repository code:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>
{
    public Set<Role> findByName(String USER);
}
```

Its working absolutely fine for me as i also had the same problem.